# JBoss AS 5.1 integration with Websphere MQ over TLS

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jms, ibm-mq

We are using the websphere MQ resource adapter (.rar) archive installed on Jboss 5.1 application server to communicate with MQ.

In the application code we have JMS producer and consumer which are able to send/receive messages to MQ.

The next step I want to do is **enable SSL on the MQ channel and configure JBoss SSLCipherSuite** so the messages can be sent with TLS enabled.

We also have firewalls and Load balancers sitting  in between our app server and web sphere MQ.

I looked at some articles but apparently there are several ways to use TLS for JMS communication.

I need some guidance on the following questions -

- What configuration is needed in Jboss to start using TLS for send and receive messages. Where should this configuration be placed? I referred to the following link in IBM documentation which mentions SSLCipherSuite : [IBM MQ 7.5 SSL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032390_.htm#q032390_)
- Do the certificates installed on Websphere MQ have to be installed on the Jboss application server? I understand that JSSE needs to be configured but I am not sure of the steps needed. Does it means simply copying the keystore and trust store to somewhere in jboss installation?
- How does it work in a clustered environment? Do the certificates have to be copied to all Jboss instances?
- Do the certificates have to be installed on the Load balancers? I believe Load balancer plays a role only for HTTP requests, not for JMS-MQ messages.
- Typically are the ports different in an enterprise for TLS and non-TLS JMS communication? I understand that the TLS enabled ports have to be opened in the firewalls as well.

Below is the connection factory we use for the communication.

```
<tx-connection-factory>

    <jndi-name>jmsConnFac</jndi-name>

    <!-- Indicate that the connection factory supports only local transactions -->

    <local-transaction/>

    <!-- Indicate that the connection factory supports XA transactions -->

    <!-- <xa-transaction/> -->

    <!-- rar-name is the actual RAR file name, in this case wmq.jmsra.rar -->

    <rar-name>wmq.jmsra.rar</rar-name>

    <!-- connection-definition is the ConnectionFactory interface

      defined in the ra.xml -->

    <connection-definition>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</connection-definition>
    <!-- Tell JBoss not to prefix the jndi name of the CF with the java: context and thus allow it to be looked up externally-->
    <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>

    <config-property name="channel" type="java.lang.String">SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN</config-property>

    <config-property name="hostName" type="java.lang.String">localhost</config-property>

    <config-property name="port" type="java.lang.String">1414</config-property>
    <config-property name="queueManager" type="java.lang.String">QM</config-property>
    <config-property name="transportType" type="java.lang.String">CLIENT</config-property>
    <!-- define security domain -->
    <security-domain-and-application>JmsXARealm</security-domain-and-application>
</tx-connection-factory>
```

**EDIT:**

- Java version 1.6.45
- MQ version 7.5.3
- JBoss version 5.1 EAP
- MQ resource adapter version 7.5.9 (From fix pack)

Comment: 1.  What version of Java are both servers running? 2. What version is the WebSphere MQ RAR. 3. What version is the WebSphere server.

Comment: IBM MQ 7.5 is out of support best to go with v8.0 or higher.  The IBM MQ classes need to have access to a minimum of a trust store that includes the signer certs for the MQ queue manager certificates, if you plan to present a client cert you will also need a key store that contains that cert and the queue manager will need to trust it as well. Unless your load balancers are offloading TLS on your MQ connections I would't think they need to be concerned with the certs.

Comment: IBM MQ can and typically does use the same port for both TLS and non-TLS MQ connections.  If you like you could start up multiple LISTENERS on different ports for the same queue manager if you needed to split it by port, but at the MQ level any LISTENER can communicate with or with TLS.  At the MQ channel level you can of course restrict which channels require TLS.  Note for oracle Java you need to set the java system property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` so that Oracle CipherSuite mappings can be used.

Comment: @JGlass Added information.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks for the info josh. So if i create a certificate on my Jboss application i have to import it to the trust store of MQ and also import MQ's certs into Jboss trust store?

Comment: MQ v8.0 and later (the only currently supported versions) require Java 1.7 or later, so unless you upgrade Java you will be stuck on a unsupported version of MQ.  If you are using self-signed certs then you would need to copy the public key the qmgr cert to the JBOSS keystore and from the JBOSS cert to the queue manager key store.  If you are using a CA to sign the certs then they each only need the CA chain in the keystore.

Comment: I don't know about the JBOSS specific questions you asked but if it would be helpfull I can post an answer with the MQ queue manager and IBM MQ classes for JMS specific questions that I provided input on.

Comment: Glad you jumped in @JoshMc as you're way more knowledgeable on this... also, in case it matters, it looks like Java 6 only supports TLS1.0 which is end of life - may not matter in your scenario but might be worth upgrading!

Comment: Thanks @JGlass, i understand the versions in use are very old and not supported any more but upgrade is not an option. I need to make it work with existing versions with whatever TLS version that is supported.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc . Yes please add that answer